# What's this white floating sediment in my bottles of twisted tea?

Tags: specialty-beers

Okay so I purchased 2 six packs of bottles each bottle containing different amounts of  this whitish colored sediment at the bottom of the bottle all of which aren't expired, if shaked well will dissappear. Anyone know what it is and is it safe to drink?[image]

Comment: Can you take a snap of the ingredients list?

Answer (score 3):

If the bottles have not been tampered with, the brew is perfectly safe to drink. [Sediment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dregs) can be formed by several factors including ingredients, filtering, temperature, and conditioning/storage...

> What are the ingredients in Twisted Tea?
>   Our delicious Twisted Tea products include a malt base made from beer, tea, natural flavors, and sugar. - [Twisted Tea FAQs](http://www.twistedtea.com/faqs)
>
> After taking the firkin out of “cold storage” (should never be colder then 45 degrees F if for any appreciable length of time), you then want to bring the cask up to cellar/serving temperature of 51 – 56 degrees F. At this rising temperature, the finings are most effective in attracting yeast and together they SLOWLY sink to the bottom forming a bed of sediment. [Pic(k) of the Week: Sam Adams fenced-in](http://www.yoursforgoodfermentables.com/2010_02_01_archive.html)
>
> Blue Hills King's Kolsch is an imperial version of the style, packing an ABV of 7.25 percent. The beer pours a dark chestnut into a tulip glass. It's unfiltered; chunks of sediment swirl and drift slowly to the bottom. Baked bread and faint flowers form the nose. [New Paulaner Bar at TD Garden; new beer offerings in the arena](http://archive.boston.com/lifestyle/food/blogs/99bottles/2013/09/)

You likely noticed this when you pulled a cold one out of the fridge. You are more than likely seeing some sort of combination of yeast, tea, and sugar which is corroborated by the solubility....